# display:flexにおける子要素の動き

Tags: html, css

ご回答頂けると幸いです。
単純な質問なのかもしれませんが、display:flexを使って５つの.flex_itemsを横に並べようと思ったのですが、折り返した後に縦に隙間が発生してしまいます。

親要素であるmainのheightを600pxにすれば縦の隙間ができることなく折り返してくれるのですが、600px以上だと隙間が発生してしまいます。
flexの仕様なのでしょうか？

ブラウザーはsafari・chrome・FireFox（全て最新）で試しましたが一緒でした。

[image: html・cssのソース]

[image: 実際の表示]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`align-content: flex-start;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)（既定値は`stretch`）でしょうか。

Comment: align-content: flex-start;で解決しました！ありがとうございます。